# Can I have a recursive JavaScript function inside a $.getJSON function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, recursion

I have a JSON document of variable depth. An example:

```
[
    {
        "type": "firsttype",
        "text": {
            "id": "content"
        }
    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the values of certain keys, say `text`. Since I do not know where these keys might appear in the .JSON, I need to use a recursive function. I then try to display these keys and values in a HTML file.

I have a preliminary attempt here:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function getText (oValue, sKey) {
    links = [];
    if (typeof oValue == "object" || typeof oValue == "array") {
        for (i in oValue) {
            getText (oValue [i], i);
        }
    } else {
        links.push ( "<li id='" + oValue + "'>" + sKey + "</li>" );
    }

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: links.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

When I load the page locally or remotely or on `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, I get no errors and nothing on the page. What am I doing wrong? I have included all the JS in the `$.getJSON` call so no async issues arise.

In the future I would also like to include a regexp check so I can extract values with a certain string, e.g. `/http/`. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you copy a full structure of this JSON for us?

Comment: add an error handler....could be a parse error or failed request. We have no way to know but you need to isolate problem. Also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: @Pointy I think if that `appendTo` jquery stuff was somehow outside of `getText` function and wasn't called everytime, it would have made some sense to have `links` as a global.

Comment: @AbbasMashayekh, that `appendTo` jquery stuff *should be* outside of `getText` and only called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers cover most of the things that you should consider, I think I'll just post a solution for your actual problem. :)

You want to traverse an arbitrary JSON and search for a specific key, and may have a condition on its value. Then you want to return all values for your specified key (that pass your condition if specified).

Consider you have the following json:

```
{
    "hello": "some text",
    "object": {
        "key1": "hello!",
        "key2": "Bye!"
    },
    "array": [{
        "some_key1": "blah blah blah",
        "some_key2": 24
    }, {
        "some_key1": "ghiojd",
        "some_key2": 13
    }],
    "numeric_array": [2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

This snippet will search the above json for `some_key1` that its value starts with `blah`:

```js
function regexpConditionFactory(regex) {
    return function(value) { return regex.test(value); };
}

function searchObjectForKey(obj, key, condition, result) {
    if ($.isPlainObject(obj)) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!condition || ($.isFunction(condition) && condition(obj[key])))
                result.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }

    if ($.isPlainObject(obj) || $.isArray(obj)) {
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
                searchObjectForKey(obj[k], key, condition, result);
        }
    }
}

$.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
    var res = [];

    searchObjectForKey(data, 'some_key1', regexpConditionFactory(/^blah/), res);

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        'html': res.map(function(value) { return '<li>' + value + '</li>'; }).join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the declaration of variable links :
it must be outside the recursive function i think.
inside the function it will be reinitialized every time.

```
var links = [];

$.getJSON("file.json", function getText (oValue, sKey) {

         if (typeof oValue == "object" || typeof oValue == "array") {
            for (i in oValue) {
                getText (oValue [i], i);
                }
         } else {
                links.push ( "<li id='" + oValue + "'>" + sKey + "</li>" );
           }

           $( "<ul/>", {
                       "class": "my-new-list",
                       html: links.join( "" )
           }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your function definition outside of the event handler:

```
 function getText (links, oValue, sKey) {


         if (typeof oValue == "object" || typeof oValue == "array") {
            for (i in oValue) {
                getText (links, oValue [i], i);
                }
         } else {
             if(oValue && sKey)
                links.push ( "<li id='" + oValue + "'>" + sKey + "</li>" );
         }

           $( "<ul/>", {
                       "class": "my-new-list",
                       html: links.join( "" )
           }).appendTo( "body" );
};

$.getJSON("file.json", function(data, success){
  var links = [];  

  getText (links, data, 0);
});
```

Feel free to edit this if there are errors.

The aim is to pass the links array in to the recursive function, and to avoid mixing the named function definition with the getJSON, for clarity at least, and to ensure you can pass an initialized sKey.

Answer (score 0):

### You can, but in your case you probably shouldn't

You *can* pass a named function as a callback function — which is useful for recursion (*See: [Using Named Callback Functions In Javascript Methods](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1989-using-named-callback-functions-in-javascript-methods.htm), Ben Nadel)* — but in your case, you probably shouldn't.

Based on your example, there are some things you will want to do before and after you invoke a recursive function. These things, such as declaring variables and appending elements to the body, will need to happen [once] outside of recursion.

So, pass an anonymous function as your callback that contains your recursive function definition and invokes it as needed.

In your case, you'll want to invoke it for each object returned in the JSON response array. So, you can put it inside of an iterator as well. Here I used jQuery's `$.each()` for convenience.

```js
/* FUNCTION THAT MAKES JSON REQUEST */
function doJsonThing() {
  
  /* BEGIN REWRITE OF OP's EXAMPLE CODE */
  $.getJSON('file.json', function (json) {
    var links = [];
    function getText (key, val) {
      if (typeof val === 'object' || typeof val === 'array') {
        for (i in val) {
          getText(i, val[i]);
        }
      } else {
        links.push('<li id="' + val + '">' + key + ' (' + val + ')</li>' );
      }
    }
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {
      getText(key, val);
    });
    $('<ul/>', {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      "html" : links.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
  });
  /* END REWRITE OF EXAMPLE CODE */
  
}

/* THE FOLLOWING IS NOT PART OF THE EXAMPLE,
// IT IS JUST USED TO SIMULATE A SERVER RESPONSE */

/* BEGIN UNIT TEST */
// CREATE CLOSURE TO RETURN DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
function json_response(response) {
  return function (url, success) {
    success(response);
  };
}

// OVERRIDE $.getJSON WITH DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
$.getJSON = json_response(
  
  // SIMULATED CONTENTS OF 'file.json'
  $.parseJSON(
    '['
  + '  {'
  + '    "type": "firsttype",'
  + '    "text": {'
  + '      "id": "content"'
  + '    }'
  + '  },'
  + '  {'
  + '    "type": "secondtype",'
  + '    "text": {'
  + '      "id": "other"'
  + '    }'
  + '  }'
  + ']'
  )
);
doJsonThing();
/* END UNIT TEST */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```